# Is it possible to resume my save game after erasing my profile?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I accidentally erased my profile of xbox360 where my GTA V save file is stored. I tried moving the save to a new profile, but my xbox said I can't move from profile to profile. Then I clicked copy it said the same thing.

How can I start again from where I erased it (witch was 60.34% of the game)?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's impossible to change the owner of the save game. *However*, if it was an Xbox Live (**Gold** *or* **Silver**) you could recover the Gamertag. You can do this by opening the guide, choosing sign in, and at the bottom of the list of accounts
, choose the option that says recover Gamertag.

This link might help:
https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/profile-move-delete

Merry Christmas!

Comment: I can confirm that it is impossible to change the owner of a save game legally. That being said, it only counts for games past 2007. Early games' save were not always tied to an owner. You can see it by browsing to the save file on your drive. It will tell you who the owner is. Recovering your profile should work just fine!